# Exception: 300 at tumbler_detect_headphone+0x1c/0x50 on iMac G4

Tags: sound, mac, live-cd

I've made a live CD of Ubuntu 13.04, downloaded from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/release/), which I'm trying to run on my iMac G4. However, upon typing `live` into the command line at boot, the nice startup screen shows up (with the five little dots). After a few dozen seconds, though, I see a bunch of white text on a black background.

The text is primarily a bunch of memory addresses, but there is some English, reproduced here:

```
NIP [d3b17cec] tumbler_detect_headphone+0x1c/0x50 [snd_powermac]
LR [d3b19068] device_change_handler+0x44/0x264 [snd_powermac]

....
```

<sup>(I don't feel like copying the whole thing out right now - it's a screenfull).</sup>

I do have the headphones plugged in, if that makes a difference.

Is there a way to install Ubuntu on my iMac G4?

Comment: Hm, still need an answer to this? You should definitely try a newer version.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should @Seth. Maybe I will in a day or two. Although I found a solution in the meantime.

Comment: Gonna post an answer then?

Comment: Nah, my solution was to use a different machine :P